# Objective-C #ifdef DEBUG is TRUE when the app is distributed?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, debugging, firebase-analytics

In my project, I am sharing events to `Firebase Analytics` and other analytics platform

When an event occurs I am checking whether the scheme is in debug mode:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define sharedAnalytics NO
#else
#define sharedAnalytics YES
#endif
```

When debugging in `Xcode` evetything seems to work as expected:

-When changing the build configuration in scheme to `Release`, `sharedAnalytics` is true, and the event is fired,

when changing the  build configuration to `Debug` - `sharedAnalytics` is false.

But the app in Appstore stopped firing those events somewhere in Jan 2020, both in `Firebase Analytics` and in `AppsFlyer`.

In the Android app everything works.

From what I know, when the app is compiled for Appstore (or Testflight) it automatically switches to Release build configuration, but it looks like it's not?

My questions are:

-Do I need to make sure I am in Release mode before uploading an app to Appstore?

-What changed in the beginning of 2020?

Thanks!

EDIT:
This is where I check `sharedAnalytics`

```
- (void)logFirebaseEvent:(NSString*)eventName params:(NSDictionary*)params{
    if (sharedAnalytics) {
        [FIRAnalytics logEventWithName:eventName parameters:params];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"%@", sharedAnalytics == nil ? @"sharedAnalytics is nil" : @"sharedAnalytics == NO");
    }
}
```

When in `DEBUG` prints "sharedAnalytics is nil"

When in `RELEASE` prints logs the event.

Comment: @skaak the preprocessor macros set correct, what do you mean by " if there slipped in a sharedAnalytics definition per chance"?

Comment: Sorry our comments crossed ... I mean maybe you #defined sharedAnalytics somewhere else e.g. in the preprocessor macros or anywhere else in your code? Maybe grep for define and sharedAnalytics in the same line (in your code) also?

Comment: @skaak The thing is, when I am running the app in xcode everything behaves as expected ( as mentioned in the original question ), the problem occurs in the already uploaded app, because I assume who ever uploaded it didn't change the Build Configuration in schemes to Release, even though from what I know, when you compile an app to Appstore it automatically changes to Release?  If it isn't the case ( or isn't the case since beginning of 2020 for any reason ) We need to start making sure we change the build config to release state before uploading the app :)

Comment: @skaak p.s: I've uploaded the app to Testflight right know and made sure it's in Release state and changed it back to Debug after uploading, so if I will see events in the next couple of days from the testers my suspicions will be true.

Comment: thanks! Yes it seems strange and all I am really saying is double check your defines and its logic. I think I'll delete some comments just to declutter a bit.

Comment: Actually this is why I suspect the logic since that part (switching to RELEASE) is sort of taken care of automatically ... maybe post code where you actually check the sharedAnalytics?

Comment: When you submit the app it uses the *Archive* scheme, doesn't it.  Is that set to *Release* mode?  Also why not add some logging when analytics are on or off, which will be much quicker to test.

Comment: Yes, may be you just submitted debug in appstore

Comment: @Cy-4AH Are you positive it is possible to submit debug in Appstore? as for what I know, no.

Comment: @skaak edited and added the if statement code

Answer (score 1):

Ok Vadim, not that this will solve the problem, but when you check this is a bit better

```
- (void)logFirebaseEvent:(NSString*)eventName params:(NSDictionary*)params{
    if (sharedAnalytics) {
        [FIRAnalytics logEventWithName:eventName parameters:params];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"sharedAnalytics == NO");
    }
}
```

Technically that

```
sharedAnalytics == nil
```

evaluates to

```
sharedAnalytics == NO
```

which is true and so it reports it as nil.

The problem is this still leaves an `NSLog` in your production / release code, so maybe you need to do that differently. Again, this is moot relative to your problem, just doing the tests a bit better. Anyway, herewith an idea.

Do the define as follows.

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#undef sharedAnalytics
#else
#define sharedAnalytics
#endif
```

To be extremely pure, you should use caps and reduce that to a single branch but lets not go there right now ...

Then when you test do as follows

```
- (void)logFirebaseEvent:(NSString*)eventName params:(NSDictionary*)params{
#ifdef sharedAnalytics
        [FIRAnalytics logEventWithName:eventName parameters:params];
#else
        NSLog(@"sharedAnalytics == NO");
#endif
}
```

While this looks a lot like your original code and does not solve the direct problem you have, it is better since when you compile for DEBUG you get the NSLog bit and when you compile for RELEASE that code is stripped completely from your release version.

What do you get for all this? You should strip all NSLog's from release code as it has performance implications.

Comment: thanks  for the response, actually I've added the NSLog just for  this post and originally it isn't exist

Comment: Ok - thanks. So are you getting any test results at the moment?

Comment: waiting for QA dep

Answer (score 0):

Debug, Release, Appstore is just build configurations.
Xcode by default just create Debug and Release configurations in new projects.
There is two possible ways to define macros:

1. in code by `#define ...`
2. in build settings in `GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS` parameter

May be you have copied Appstore from Debug or may be you have `#define DEBUG` some where
May be you have DEBUG=0

Proper way to check for DEBUG is

```
#if defined(DEBUG) && DEBUG
#define sharedAnalytics NO
#else
#define sharedAnalytics YES
#endif
```

May be you also checking sharedAnalytics wrong.
In both cases `#ifdef sharedAnalytics` gives `YES`

Comment: `#if DEBUG` will fail if `DEBUG` is not defined, so the OP's code is fine.

Comment: @trojanfoe but if it's defined like `#define DEBUG=0`?

Comment: It won't be (by default).  If he's setting it like that then that's an error, so you shouldn't need to check if it's both defined and non-zero as you suggest.

Comment: @trojanfoe then it should be defined without any values, if defining `DEBUG=0` is wrong

Comment: It is defined without values; i.e. `#define DEBUG`.  That's what Xcode sets by default.  So the OPs `#ifdef DEBUG` is correct.

Comment: @trojanfoe my xcode is defining `GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS = DEBUG=1 $(inherited)` by default

Comment: Ah OK, I'm wrong about that then, but the test `#ifdef DEBUG` is fine in the OPs code - no need to check if it's both defined and non-zero.